# Convert a string like "1 hour and 22.5 seconds" into seconds to make calculations

Tags: python

I am using python, and would like to read a log file that contain info about time.

The string is like this: "1 hour and 22.5 seconds". or "41 seconds" or "22.3 seconds"; Not sure exactly what would be the best way to handle this case. I do not have control on how the data is written, I can just process it.

I was thinking to read the string; then separate it in single strings; so if I find "hour" at position [2] in the string list, I add 3600 seconds in an int variable; if I find minutes then I get the value and check if it has decimals or not, and parse it as such; adding it to the hours if present.

Is this something reasonable or there is a better way? Kinda prone to error to base your conversion on positions that may not be the same for different strings.

Comment: It's hard to give general advice, as there's no strict definition given of how your data is going to be defined, but I'd consider splitting the string by " ", looking through the elements for the strings `hour/hours`, `minute/minutes`, and `second/seconds`, and then multiply the value that preceded it (using 1 if given singular form IE: hour) by an appropriate scalar to convert it to seconds, and then grab the sum.

Comment: What about using a `regex`? for the example that you mentioned this `re.findall('\d+\.?\d?', s)` gives `['1', '22.5']`

Comment: @ettanany the right context is needed for the calculation, but I would go with regex too.

Comment: Can you provide some examples that covers all the scenarios that you have? are they all like "a hour(s) b minute(s) c second(s)"?

Comment: What about pytimeparse https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytimeparse/1.1.0 ?

Comment: Google can do this. Would it be possible to bend their API to your purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without regex, you can do something like this:

```
times = ['1 hour and 22.5 seconds', '3 hours 4 minutes and 15 seconds', '22.3 seconds', '6 hours']
# attempt to normalize the input data
times = [t.lower().replace('and','').replace('hours','hour').replace('minutes','minute').replace('seconds','second').replace('  ',' ') for t in times]

secondsList = map(getseconds, times)

def getseconds(sTime):
    seconds = 0.0
    S = sTime.split()
    if 'hour' in S:
        seconds += (3600 * float(S[S.index('hour')-1]))
    if 'minute' in S:
        seconds += (60 * float(S[S.index('minute')-1]))
    if 'second' in S:
        seconds += float(S[S.index('second')-1])
    return seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions:

```
UNIT2SECONDS = {
    'hour': 3600,
    'minute': 60,
    'second': 1,
}

text = "4 hours, 43 minutes and 3 seconds"
seconds = sum(sum(map(float, re.findall("([.0-9]+)\s+%s" % k))) * v for k, v in UNIT2SECONDS.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is not bad. I would use regex to find the occurences of hours, minutes and seconds and use grouping to get the corresponding number. As an example for the case of hours, consider this:

```
hours = re.match(r'(\d{1,2})(\shour[s]?)', "1 hour and 50 minutes")
if hours:
   seconds = hours.group(1) * 60 * 60
```

The brackets `()` allow for grouping, which allow you to easily extract the number. You can perform the same for minutes and seconds. If the regex does not return anything, `hours` will be `None`, thus you can easily check for `if hours:` and then perform your math on the converted string.